# on mouse out return to original image source

Tags: javascript

I'm manipulating image source with this code below, works great, but I'm failing to add a mouseout function (so when not hovering over one of the specified `<li>`) the image source of the one being changed in the code below, returns to how it was before any hover took place, any thoughts?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var imageContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.image_left')[0];

  function initImageHover(selector) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    console.log(elements);
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
      createHover(elements[i]);
    };
  }

  function createHover(that) {
    that.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      var src = that.getAttribute('data-src');
      if (src) {
        imageContainer.src = src;
      }
    });
    that.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      imageContainer.src = '';
    });
  }

  initImageHover('li.one > a');
});

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var imageContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.image_left2')[0];

  function initImageHover(selector) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    console.log(elements);
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
      createHover(elements[i]);
    };
  }

  function createHover(that) {
    that.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      var src = that.getAttribute('data-src');
      if (src) {
        imageContainer.src = src;
      }
    });
    that.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      imageContainer.src = '';
    });
  }

  initImageHover('li.two > a');
});
```

**Update** the original image; is outside of the li elements, and is in the mark-up like below. Currently just getting image null / dead images with two answered attempts.

```
<div class="block2wrap">
<div class="left">
<article class="left_image">
<img src="images/verycoolimage.jpg" class="image_left">
</article>
```

Comment: Set default src to variable, and use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the original image src in a variable and use it when the mouse leaves:

```
function createHover (that) {

  var original = that.getAttribute('src');

  that.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    var src = that.getAttribute('data-src');
    if (src) {
      imageContainer.src = src;
    }
  });
  that.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    imageContainer.src = original;
  });
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zhhwvck/).

Comment: it's saying image source null in console, seems to begin to do what i'm looking for but the image is dead not storing properly!

Comment: This is returning, dead / null image reference, any ideas?

Comment: just tried this   var original = document.getElementsByClassName("image_left");

Comment: @YourConscious Be sure that you're selecting the correct elements. I have updated my answer with a JSFiddle to prove that the concept works.

Comment: OK, I wasn't specific enough I supposed. I opened a new question; original image source is NOT within li where hover source is being toggled. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846733/on-mouseleave-revert-image-back-to-origin-source-that-is-outside-where-hover-dat

Answer (score 1):

add this lines to the mouseover function (before you set the src)

```
var _src = that.getAttribute('src');
that.setAttribute('data-old-src', _src);
```

Change this line in mouseleave

```
imageContainer.src = '';
```

to that

```
imageContainer.src = that.getAttribute('data-old-src');
```

Comment: This is returning, dead / null image reference, any ideas?

Comment: can you provide a link to the page or to a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846733/on-mouseleave-revert-image-back-to-origin-source-that-is-outside-where-hover-dat